# How to draw a BufferedImage with a color tint

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, tint

I'm trying to draw a `BufferedImage` to my `Canvas` with a varying color tint, but can't find any real working examples.

I don't want to generate a new tinted `BufferedImage`, but repeatedly draw a `BufferedImage` to my GUI in real time with varying color tints, depending on various conditions.
An image drawn with a tint color of `0xFF0000` will be drawn as a red-only image, while a tint color of `0xFFFFFF` won't affect the image.

How would I accomplish such a thing using the `Graphics2D` instance of my control?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Drawing an Image | Filtering Images | LookupOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm afraid that there isn't anything there regarding image tinting. It does seem to say that I should use `LookupOp` to accomplish this, there are no examples of this.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [ColorTintFilter](http://code.google.com/p/filthy-rich-clients/source/browse/trunk/filthyRichClients-16/src16.StaticEffects.Blur/org/progx/artemis/image/ColorTintFilter.java?r=2) from [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) book can help you. The relevant sample chapter from the book is available [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1013851&seqNum=8).

Here is a code snippet that uses the filter:

```
BufferedImage image = ...;
BufferedImageOp imageFilter = new ColorTintFilter(Color.RED, 1.0f);
image = imageFilter.filter(image, null);
```