# SWT GC change image color

Tags: java, swt, image-manipulation

I have an image (that shows a circle like this one http://icons.mysitemyway.com/legacy-icon/016945-3d-transparent-glass-icon-symbols-shapes-shapes-circle/ in the image registry!

I want to change the color of circle from the image in red. Can someone tell me how can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Note to the people downvoting/closing: The question is not unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with GC alone; the GC offers you the commands to create a new image by rendering a circle but you can't modify existing images (much).

You will have to load the image into a `BufferedImage`. Afterwards, you can use pixel manipulation to do what you want.

There are many answers regarding pixel manipulation here; here are some that should get you started:

- [How to convert a BufferedImage to a certain colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853384/how-to-convert-a-bufferedimage-to-a-certain-colour)
- [How to draw a BufferedImage with a color tint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794189/how-to-draw-a-bufferedimage-with-a-color-tint)
- http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/CurvesFilter.html